# rails typus routing error when creating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, typus

i installed typus for a small rails application and i want to setup auth via mysql database and I followed the steps on the typus wiki sites. Everything works fine, but when I want to login to admin: localhost:3000/admin I have to enter an e-mail address and then I'll be routed to: http://localhost:3000/admin/account/new but I get a routing error. In my routes.rb config file I have only this line enabled:   match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

I couldn't find any help. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

did you do all the [installation steps](https://github.com/typus/typus/wiki)?  please copy-paste the output here:

1. rake routes
2. cat Gemfile |grep typus
3. cat config/routes

Comment: you can [see](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces.html) other admins if necessary

Comment: rake routes: [link]http://pastebin.com/fx2wQJcD[/link]
Gemfile: gem 'typus', :git => 'git://github.com/typus/typus.git'
routes:`testapp::Application.routes.draw do
  
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end`

Comment: I see what you mean, run 2 commands in Terminal

    1. $ rails generate typus:migration
    2. $ rake db:migrate

Comment: then you will be able to signup with admin account